# enhanced for loop won't loop! java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Trying to create a simple java program that uses the java GUI library to simply display a square, a button, and a circle that changes colors upon clicks. Everything compiles and runs except I can't get the (actionListener) button to change its text upon every click!!

I tried a regular for loop and an enhanced for loop, but my button will only display its original text and will display only the last text in the ArrayList when cicking it...

```
package chapter12;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class SimpleGui3C implements ActionListener {
  JFrame frame;
  JButton button;
  public static void main(String [] args ) {
    SimpleGui3C run = new SimpleGui3C();

    run.go();
  }

  public void go() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    button = new JButton("FUCKING GENIUS!");
    button.addActionListener(this);

    MyDrawPanel panel = new MyDrawPanel();
    Gradient_Random gradient = new Gradient_Random();

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, gradient);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, button);

    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    ArrayList<String> txtList = new ArrayList<String>();
    txtList.add("bOOm!");
    txtList.add("SpLaT!");
    txtList.add("FUCKING GENIUS!");
    txtList.add("whoOSH!");
    txtList.add("PoW!");



    for (String txt : txtList) {
    frame.repaint();
    button.setText(txt);


   }

   }
```

Comment: On each iteration you replace text of the button with element of the array. So when iterations are finished it will show the last element. Try this code: `button.setText(button.getText() + " " + txt);`

Comment: The code is working as expected. Note that you will loop through the `ArrayList`, from the first item `"b00m!"` until the last `"PoW!"` and it's replacing the text of `button` as intended. It does it so fast that you cannot see all values in the button text but the last element in the list. If you want to see each text in the button one by one, add a system pause or something similar, or try something else.

Comment: @Ivan i tried your code but after displaying the original txt, then the last array item upon the button click, the button then displays the entire string on one line upon the third click

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza thats kind of what I surmised, but I am a beginner and do not know how to "add a system pause"

again I realize that his is a fairly simple problem, but I still can't get it to work as intended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One final addition...
In the previous answer the button throws several runtime exceptions after four clicks. (because the code increments x, but the length of the array is only equal to 4). I added this code to stop it from blowing up. You could also probably use Math.random * txtList.length and cast the result back into an int variable...

```
    button.setText(txtList.get(X));

    if (X > -1 ) {
        X++;
        if (X == 5) {
            X -= 5;
        }
        }

    frame.repaint();

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just not using the loop.DUH! (right?) Every time the method is called the entire for loop would iterate all the way through. I'm actually glad that nobody gave me a direct answer, the little nudge I received was enough to push me in the right direction. After all, in programming I PROMISE, you will learn better if you find solutions by trying your best to work out your own problems. This site is great!

Anyway I deleted the entire for loop and added only 2 lines

```
static int X;
```

and inside the actionPerformed() method i added

```
button.setText(txtList.get(X);
```